# XSLT - move child and parent ID attribute and remove double space after number in string

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input xml is like,

```
<section level="2">
<title>1.  Wound Healing<target id="c001"/><target id="page3"/></title>
<figure id="c001_f001" counter="yes">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-1</emph> Hypertrophic scar.</para></legend>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f001.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
<figure counter="yes">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-2</emph> Keloid scar.</para></legend>
<subfigure>
<graphic id="c001_f002" position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
........
</section>
```

Required Output as,

```
<section level="2">
<title>1. Wound Healing<target id="c001"/><target id="page3"/></title>
<figure counter="yes">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-1</emph> Hypertrophic scar.</para>   </legend>
<subfigure id="c001_f001">
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f001.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
<figure counter="yes">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-2</emph> Keloid scar.</para></legend>
<subfigure id="c001_f002">
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
........
</section>
```

My xslt is like as,

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
<xsl:variable name="fig1" select="parent::figure/@id"></xsl:variable>      
<xsl:copy>     
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>            
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:value-of select="$fig1"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>          
<xsl:when test="subfigure/@id[not(contains(.,'c'))]">
<xsl:if test="subfigure/@id[not(contains(.,'c'))]">
<xsl:variable name="fig1" select="graphic/@id"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy>    
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:value-of select="$fig1"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>            
</xsl:if>
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The above mentioned XSLT is working on only to move figure id into subfigure element. But we are unable to move graphic id into subfigure element. Alos, we need to remove double space which is appearing in  element after "1.  " number. Could you please guide us.

Comment: I have created separate xslt for 2nd part which is to move graphic ID into "subfigure" element but still it's not working.

Comment: I have removed the double space which is appearing within "title" element. Please provide the xslt to move ID. Thanku.

Comment: What should happen if both the `figure` and the `graphic` have an `id` attribute? Which would should be used on the `subfigure`?

Comment: Also, if your XSLT sample the one you are actually used? The sample shown contains a closing `</xsl:choose>` tag, but there is not opening tag to match it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932795/xslt-to-keep-parent-attribute-value-only-on-first-child-element/46933757#46933757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the solutions in your other post ([XSLT - To keep parent attribute value only on first child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932795/xslt-to-keep-parent-attribute-value-only-on-first-child-element/46933757#46933757)), you can apply the same method, just the other way round:

```
<!-- identity copy -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove id from figure when 1st subfigure does not have id -->
<xsl:template match="figure[descendant::subfigure[not(@id)]]/@id"/>

<!-- insert id from figure into subfigure -->
<xsl:template match="subfigure[not(@id)][ancestor::figure[1]/@id][1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::figure[1]/@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove id from graphic when superordinate subfigure does not have id -->
<xsl:template match="graphic[ancestor::subfigure[not(@id)]]/@id"/>

<!-- insert id from graphic into subfigure -->
<!-- (set priority="+1" or "-1" to avoid possible conflicts with other template) -->
<xsl:template match="subfigure[not(@id)][descendant::graphic[1]/@id]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::graphic[1]/@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace double whitespace in title -->
<xsl:template match="title[contains(., '  ')]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '  ', ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

For whitespace control within `<title>`, you can work directly on text node (just expand the xpath expression if you need to do this also on other elements).

Comment: Thanku for your response friedemann...It's working perfectly.